# TypeScript generics: how to define type T which is structurally the same as other type S

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, structural-typing, structural-equality

I have a notion of a `Step`, which requires value of type `A` as an input and gives out a value of type `B`.

```
class Step<A, B> {
  constructor(private readonly f: (a: A) => B) { }

  public run(a: A): B {
    return this.f(a);
  }
}
```

Now I would like to compose two steps, so I end up with something like this inside `class Step`:

```
  public andThen<C, D>(nextStep: Step<C, D>): Step<A, D> {
    return new Step<A, D>((state: A) => {
      const b: B = this.f(state);
      return nextStep.run(b);  // <---- compile error, B and C have no relation defined
    });
  }
```

What I would like to achieve is to somehow tell the type system that we can pass type `B` to a function which expects type `C` (structural typing should check that all fields in `C` are present in `B`), so that the line `return nextStep.run(b)` works fine.

Example:

```
const stepA: Step<{}, {a: number, b: string}> = new Step((input: {}) => ({ a: 5, b: "five" }));
const stepB: Step<{a: number}, {c: number}> = new Step((input: {a: number}) => ({c: input.a + 5}));

const steps = stepA.andThen(stepB)
```

As you can see `stepB` requires as an input `{a: number}`, so it can be fed an output from `stepA` which is `{a: number, b: string}`. But I cannot figure out how to define the relation in `andThen`. Any thoughts how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type SubType<T, WiderT> = T extends WiderT ? WiderT : never;

class Step<A, B> {
  constructor(private readonly f: (a: A) => B) { }

  public run(a: A): B {
    return this.f(a);
  }

  public andThen<C, D>(nextStep: Step<SubType<B, C> | B, D>): Step<A, D> {
    return new Step<A, D>((state: A) => {
      const b = this.f(state);
      return nextStep.run(b);
    });
  }
}

const stepAB: Step<{}, {a: number, b: string}> = 
new Step((input) => ({ a: 5, b: "five" }));

const add5 = ({ a }: { a: number }) => ({ c: a + 5 });
const stepCD: Step<{ a: number }, { c: number }> = new Step(add5);


const stepAD = stepAB.andThen(stepCD);
```

The core point is `SubType` type:

```
type SubType<T, WiderT> = T extends WiderT ? WiderT : never;
```

It says that if the type extends given type then its ok, but its not then never. Pay attention how it is used:

```
SubType<B, C> | B
```

So we are saying that if type `B` extends `C`, so `B` is more specific type then `C` then we allow on that, if not we don't by `never`. Additionally we allow on `B` itself (without union there was still compilation error)

Comment: Maciej, that is exactly what I started from. But now as you can see `stepBC` doesn't need property `b: string`, so as a separate entity it shouldn't require it as an input.

`stepBC` becomes `Step<{a: number}, {c: number}>` and it doesn't work then.

This is the question how do we tell that input to `stepBC` is structurally ok when we give it output of `stepAB`

Comment: But what is a problem? You dont need to use `b`. you can work with `a` only. As you see `(input) => ({c: input.a + 5}` does not use `b`. Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: function which work on wider type {a: number} can work with {a:number, b:string} also

Comment: Check the answer now please

Comment: yes, it seems to be doing exactly what i want it to do - thank you very much for your help, appreciate it